# python-qt4 module installation Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-module

I am trying to use the code here: 
https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

When I run the code I get this error:

```
$ python javascrape.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "javascrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

After looking over many old solutions to this problem, the answer was supposed to be:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

But, I have done this and the issue persists.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Python 2.7.5

Any help would be much appreciated.

I can even run:

```
python /usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/examples/tutorials/addressbook/part1.py
```

and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/examples/tutorials/addressbook/part1.py", line 45, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment by any chance?

Comment: a VWMARE instance, yea

Comment: @dopstar what does that mean?

Comment: I mean like virtualenv for python, if you use virtualenv for python then you should install pyqt via pip install not apt-get.